# Compare objects, ignore "order" of members

Tags: c#

I have the following object.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }

    public Foo(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}
```

Now I want to override Equals and GetHashCode methods where those two objects should be treated equal (and identical hashcode).

```
var foo1 = new Foo(1, 2);
var foo2 = new Foo(2, 1);
```

I know how to write the Equals method but I struggle with the get hashcode method.

Thats my current version:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (_x * 397) ^ _y;
    }
}
```

In my current - not working solution - foo1 has a HashCode of 399 and foo2 has 795.

I need for both to be identical.

Comment: why don't you check before with an if

Comment: If the order truely doesn't matter why not always assign the min value to x and the max to y in the constructor?

Comment: @juharr didnt thought about it, but its part of John Wu's answer

Comment: @JavierJimenezMatilla its not in my hands to check it with an if x and y are getting passed to me and I handle the case

Comment: You might want to re-word your last sentance then because it is ambiguous

Comment: @RandRandom my comment pretend to be the same that john wu answer, if (f(x*y*...n) = f(n*y*....n) get min or max of the number you want to be the number... but you are asking for a condition, write the condition, was my comment. Sorry

Comment: _"better"_ - yes thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a transformation such that `f(x,y)` = `f(y,x)`. I can think of a few mathematical properties that ought to do it-- anything that is commutative ought to work, e.g. simple multiplication.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        return _x * _y;
    }
}
```

Not sure how likely convergence is, and it might be trickier with a large number of fields. As an alternative you could force the swappable parameters into a sorted order before hashing:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var x = Math.Min(_x, _y);
    var y = Math.Max(_x, _y);
    unchecked
    {
        return (x * 397) ^ y;
    }
}
```

Or, if you have three or more fields:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var a = new int[] { _x, _y, _z };
    Array.Sort(a);
    unchecked
    {
        return ((a[0] * 397) ^ a[1]) * 397 ^ a[2];
    }
}
```

Might be a cleverer way to do it with LINQ, but you get the idea.

Comment: Note @JohnWu's second example is probably better for most purposes than the first, though if hashcode is being used purely for a cheap identity check in your case then his first one is faster.  If you're using it for dictionaries or striping or something like that then his second answer should be much better overall.

Comment: Also note that Math.Min should be as fast as conceivably possible.  I think last time I checked they were using the optimal binary technique for this.

Comment: @hoodaticus yeah, I use it as a key inside a dictionary